# SQL server truncate string greater than column length

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have column Description varchar(2000) in SQL server table.
In the front end, I have HTML textarea with property maxlength=2000.
However, if I enter a string in HTML textarea with one or two enter's in string SQL server consider the string more than 2000 and truncate 4 to 5 last char of the entered string.
When I check string len() in SQL server by SQL profiler it is greater than 2000 char while inserting. This is because SQL Server considers keyboard enter (key code=13) as 2 char.
So my Question is that,

1> How I can calculate exact string length using Jquery or javascript same as length function of SQL Server? So that if I pass exact length string to SQL then it should not truncate it.

I tried to count enter sequences as well in the count

```
var num = _input1.length;
            var lineCount = (_input1.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/).length - 1);
            $("#spnCharCount").text(num + lineCount);


Code on Textarea Keyup..
$("#Description").keyup(function (event) {
        var key = event.which;
            var length = this.value.length;
        if (key >= 33 || key == 13 || key == 32) {
            var maxLength = $(this).attr("maxlength");
            if (length >= maxLength) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
           $("#spnCharDescriptionCount").text(length);
    });
```

SQL Server returns no error like "string or binary data will be truncated"
It just simply save the truncated string in column.

I have declared the variable in stored proc as @Description varchar(2000)
This may cause a problem.

Comment: If your variable for your SP is 2000, you will never get truncation error because insert will never be over 2000 characters.  Assigning more characters to a string then it holds does not generate an error, just truncates.  So that is why your never seeing that error, its being cut short on your assigning the value to your variable.

Comment: Why don't you just expand the column or reduce textarea size? If you have more than 2000 chars in textarea, you have to truncate the string anyway if you do not increase the size of the column.

Comment: Why not replacing '\r\n' with empty string before length calculation? Or event better enlarge column size to 2500 and keep the size of the text box the same?

Comment: @brad yes ..u are right but my question is that how can I calculate exact string length same as column length of my table i.e 2000 char.@Vasya I can not increase the length of a column of a table. Problem is with SQL server consider enter as 2 char length.

Comment: "keycode 13" isnt 2 characters, it's one. What you have is carriage return (char 13) and line break (char 10). Those are 2 separate characters. If you could have over 2,000 character though, then why not use an`(n)varchar(MAX)`?

Comment: Thanks, @Larnu but I can not use (n)varchar(max) as DBA suggests it might impact application performance. I will try to add char 10 in  my code if it works.

Comment: LOL can't change the database to accommodate the needs of the application because it might impact performance. That is laughably lazy and pathetic of your DBA. First of all it wouldn't need to be MAX, just increase the size a bit to maybe 2500 or even 4000 (if it is nvarchar). But refusing to accommodate the application because of the potential of performance loss is sad.

Comment: If you already have the column as varchar(2000), then growing it all the way to varchar(8000) shouldn't impact performance if you're limiting it in the front-end. I agree that MAX can have an impact, but it might be needed at times.

Comment: i agree as well.  MAX is overkill and has huge overhead due to breaking the data into multiple entries.  8000 is the absolute max size that can fit into one row.